# css :hover rotate element and keep the new position

Tags: css, rotation, transform

I there a (css?) possibility to rotate an element on `element:hover` and keep the new position when moving the mouse out?

It seems that the element rotates back to it`s default position when the cursor leaves the :hover - area.

**edit:**

now it seems to work (forgot to say, that i wanted it to happen each time/ multiple times):

```
var rotate = 360;
  $('.artistbutton360').bind({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).css("-webkit-transform","rotate("+ rotate +"deg)");
      $(this).css("-moz-transform","rotate("+ rotate +"deg)");
      $(this).css("-o-transform","rotate("+ rotate +"deg)");
      $(this).css("transform","rotate("+ rotate +"deg)");
      rotate = rotate + 360;
    }
});
```

Comment: oh, and if you want to release that "rotate" property, just to this:

`$('element').mouseout(function(){ $(this).css(whatever);});`

Comment: There won't be any pure CSS solution, using script is something easy to do. When in `:hover` state, some styles are applied, and finally the element should have a non-hover state, which will reset all the applied style and set the element to the original appearance. However I made [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9r65n/1/) as a workaround. The idea is you need to keep the `:hover` state when the mouse is over **the whole page** to style the element you want. However whenever your mouse is moved **out of the viewport**, your element's state will be restored back.

Comment: @KingKing, you should submit this as an answer. That's a great pure CSS solution.

Comment: @fuccboi thank you, however it really depends on the exact scenario you have, such as if the UI interaction is still required after hovering on the element and still keeping mouse pointer inside the document, then it will not be such great. I mean you won't be able to interact with other elements because of the curtain covering on top. You can see that via this updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/9r65n/2/

Comment: @King King Ah I see. Still, very creative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery:

```
$('element').hover(function(){
  $(this).css(whatever);
});
```

remember adding

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: ok, I tried with jquery (with addClass and removeClass), but the element still rotates back to its origin orientation. I need the element to rotate and stay in the new position . so there is no way to achieve this (?)

Comment: try with .mouseout instead of .hover

Comment: i had to use mouseenter and add 360 degrees each time that it is executed. (edit)