# :hover rotation CSS keep position on uncover

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am rotating an object with CSS upon hovering, and would like for it to remain in it's new position as you unhover it. I have searched around, but the only thing I could find is [css :hover rotate element and keep the new position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313727/css-hover-rotate-element-and-keep-the-new-position), which seems to go above and beyond.

Is this effect possible to achieve purely with CSS? I want the icon to remain at the 180 position once you stop hovering.

I used this code:

```
i.fa.fa-globe:hover { 
    color: #e9204f;
    transition: 0.9s;
    transform: rotatey(180deg);
}
```

Also it's a font-awesome icon if this makes any difference.

---

Edit - The easy CSS solution for everyone else who needs it (taken from the comments):

```
.lovernehovermarket i.fa.fa-rocket { 
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 999s;
}
```

Comment: If you're rotating 360deg, isn't the "new position" the same as the starting position?

Comment: Hello thanks a lot. Sorry that was a bad example - that one works perfect. I have three icons and one of them rotates 180 degrees only, and when I move the hover it moves back up. So I was hoping to find a simple way to make it stay at the 180 degree angle once I move the mouse. Thanks for pointing that out, gotta love Stackoverflow. Editing right away.

Answer (score 3):

I had a circular icon that I wanted to rotate on every hover, not just the first, and not rotate when un-hovered.

**Original**

I saw this problem when I had CSS that looked like this

```
.icon {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.icon:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

**Solution**

The simple solution was to put the transition inside the `:hover` psuedo class

```
.icon:hover {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

### Boom, done!

This works because I was originally setting the transition to be 0.5s by default.  In this case, that means both forward and backward.  By putting the `transition` property inside the hover, I have a 0.5s transition when hover is activated, but a 0s transition (the default) when the icon is un-hovered.  Having a 0s hover means it just instantly snaps back to position, invisibly to the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I you want a pure CSS solution, you can set a transtion time to go back to the base state quite high.

It's not for ever, but it's pretty close for most users:

```css
.test {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: tomato;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 999s 999s;
}
.test:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Hello!

This was exactly what I was looking for. Such a simple solution and it is working perfectly. I sincerely appreciate your help, sir. I really do. I uprooted you as well of course.

May I ask if there are any downsides to this CSS solution only? I am assuming there is since everyone is insisting on using the jQuery etcetera? :) 

Sorry for taking up your time. Once again thank you. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I have edited it, adding a delay, this way it won't move anything. The only downside that I can think of is that if you un-hover fast, the initial movement will not complete. And may ne some people find this "hacky" Happy that it helped !

Comment: Professional response from a professional gentleman. Once again thank you so much and for responding once again to explain exactly what you did and potential pro/cons. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Use an animation, and apply it using JS event listener, when the element is hovered (mouseover event). When the element is hovered for the 1st time, remove the event listener:

```js
var rect = document.querySelector('.rectangle')

function rotate() {
  this.classList.add('rotate');
  
  rect.removeEventListener('mouseover', rotate);
}

rect.addEventListener('mouseover', rotate);
```

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
}

.rotate {
  animation: rotate 0.5s linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: Hello!

Thank you so much for helping out. I really appreciate it. I made a little typo in my original post, I apologize. It does not rotate 360 degrees. It rotates 180 degrees and I'd like for it once you remove the hover to remain at the new 180 angle. So the icon starts by pointing upwards, then when you hover it points down. However, once I remove the hover it points upward again.

Comment: @eMikkelsen have a look at my answer, it leaves the element upside down on mouse out and doesn't animate a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You also need an initial `transform` state in the regular CSS of your element, so that it can transform between two defined states:

```css
.rotate {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.9s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.rotate:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

body {
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the rotated state, you may have to use a little JQuery to check when the transition ends and change the class so it doesn't revert back to its original state on blur.

This way the div is rotated once and then its class is changed to maintain the rotated state.

```js
$('.rotate').hover(function () { 
    $(this).addClass("animate");
    $(this).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
    function(e) {

  $(this).removeClass('rotate').addClass('rotated');

  });

});
```

```css
.rotate {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.animate {
  animation: rotate 1s linear;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  animation-play-state: running;
}
.rotated
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rotate">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to put the transform not on hover but on the main css.

not:

```
 #gear {
  width: 3vh;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: transform 200ms;

  }
}
```

but

```
#gear {
  width: 3vh;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 200ms;

  &:hover {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```